# How to authenticate WSO2IS User management APIs with commonAuthId in Java?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0. My application is already authenticated and I have commonAuthId. How to access user management APIs with the commonAuthId in Java?

Comment: How did you authenticate?

Comment: I authenticated using username and password and I need to call WSO2 APIs.